# Function passed as context value can't access updated component state when called by a consumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I am passing a function to as value to the `Context Provider` and on calling that function from the consumer, I'm getting the older state.

**Provider.jsx**

```
const MyContext = createContext();

const Provider=()=>{
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState();

  const providerFunction=()=>{
    // accessing someState
  }

<MyContext.Provider value={{providerFunction}}>
  <ConsumerComponent/>
</MyContext.Provider>
```

**Comsumer.jsx**

```
const {providerFunction} = useContext(MyContext);
```

On calling `providerFunction` from `Consumer.jsx`, providerFunction in Provider.jsx is called but `someState` is not getting the updated value, it is printing the initial value assigned to it.

I'm unable to figure out the reason for this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, actually, I was using `debounce` in `Consumer` and in `useCallback`, I missed passing `providerFunction` as a dependency.

After adding the dependency, it worked!